# Is there a reason why the writers of game of thrones are deviating so much from the books in the later seasons?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The books are very comprehensive and subplots have subplots, that have subplots.

I just watched the first 4 episodes of season 5 and I can't believe how much the show has deviated from the books here.

I do get it that they can't follow every single page of every single book and that the show  has blundered on so fast that the last book Martin wrote is being overtaken by the show at an alarming rate. Many BIG plots in the books are totally disregarded and others invented in its place.
What will become canon? it was so gut-wrenching to watch...

So I guess my question is:
Is there a real reason that the show deviates so much from the later books?
Did the writers give any RL explanations as to their reasoning?

Comment: *"The books (...) subplots have subplots, that have subplots."* Maybe that's the reason? Demands for a TV series are not the same as for books, and I am sure your average TV watcher is not nearly as patient with plot development as fantasy book lovers.

Comment: This question is too personal for it to be useful for anyone. Sounds like a rant disguised as a question to me. -1

Comment: "Yes, there is a reason. Otherwise they wouldn't have done it." There, the only answer you need. Also, this is either an unclear question or primarily opinion-based (the opinion here would be "deviating so much..."), so I'd say it deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 25):

People who are *A Song of Ice and Fire* fans are making a really big deal about how much the show is "deviating" from "the real story". Those people must not watch very many TV or movie adaptations of books or comics, because *that's always what happens*.

There are two canons. There is the *Song of Ice and Fire* canon, and there is the *Game of Thrones* canon. Consider yourself really lucky that there are only two -- fans of comic book adaptations often have to deal a lot more. For example, with the upcoming *Justice League* movie, there's going to be three *currently active* canon versions of Flash or Green Arrow. I think we're up to 6 "primary" Spider-Man canon worlds, and I've lost count of how many Batman origin stories are canon. Even when the show/movie stays close to canon, they deviate, often in significant ways (there is no Tom Bombadil in the *Lord of the Rings* movie canon, and no Peeves in *Harry Potter* movie canon).

There are a lot of reasons why a TV show would deviate from the source material, and Game of Thrones is hitting almost all of them:

- Often, book material just doesn't translate to the screen; this is particularly true when there is a lot of internal monologue going on, or a lot of people thinking about events that happened off-screen. This is why *Game of Thrones* had to invent some minor characters -- to give them an excuse to show events or hear people talking that the novels only reveal through the first-person narrator's thoughts.
- TV shows have a fixed amount of time to tell their story. A book can be as long as the author wants, only limited by what the readers are willing to buy. And fantasy readers in particular have shown themselves willing to buy *really big* books (looking at you here, *Wheel of Time* and *Stormlight Archives*). There's just no way to include every character and every plotline from the novels on the show.
- TV shows have different pacing; it's possibly for a good author to hold the readers attention with very slow-burn build up to something important, and Martin is good at doing that. He can spend a lot of time putting the pieces in place for some intrigue plot. On a TV show, that would not come across nearly as well. So, plot lines often have to be condensed, dialog shifted around in time, etc.
- TV shows have to be produced on a tight schedule, based on the demands of multiple parties (the network, the production company, the actors, etc.) Thus, when the show and the books are both on-going, it's inevitable that the show will out-pace the books. The *Game of Thrones* writers saw this coming, and started planning what was going to happen when *they* were the ones writing the original material.
- People who have read the books can, on occasion, get a superiority complex about "knowing all this stuff already". That leads to people who are fans of the show getting worried about "book spoilers" (this is a real perception, real or otherwise; someone on M&TV yesterday told me he never comes to SF&F to ask about *Game of Thrones* because people here can't help spoiling things from the books.) If the show *doesn't* follow the book directly, then there's nothing to spoil. That tends to make things fun both book readers (who no longer know what's going to happen and get to find out anew), and non-book readers (who no longer have to fear someone revealing every minor detail of the upcoming season)

Comment: Couldn't have put it better: +1

Comment: I personaly find it very distastefull that they continue to deviate so much that it is looking like something else completly. It would be like Star Wars beeing writen as books, than Lucas coming and changing everything ( Vader not beeng Lukes father, Leia Falling in love with Lando, Alderaan not getting blown to bits ) it is wrong. Not saying that i have a supereriority complex. just feeling that the showrunners are shitting all over a very, very, very nice story. and hence my question as to why? I dont care about small stuff. But BIG plots beeing changed completly... that is just... wrong...

Comment: as I said, that's standard behavior when adapting books to TV. If anything, it's amazing that they've been as faithful to the books as they were so far; perhaps that was the mistake and they set themselves up for failure later on.

Comment: @Cherubel I've learned to accept it from Peter Jackson's Tolkien adaptations (and [The Tolkien Professor's talks](http://tolkienprofessor.com) helped here). Think of it this way: The books are really good and a great story. Are the shows also telling a good story? That's the first requirement. Now, think about *why* they might be deviating from the books. What does the deviation do *for the TV story*? What place does it hold? Does the deviation make a good TV story, *with the same ideas as* the original?

Comment: @Cherubel - I don't find it distasteful at all, and I'm a huge fan of the series (just look at my history). The fact is, for a story this big to make a transition to TV you *have* to make changes. You can either do it by respecting the *spirit* of the original material, the way D & D are doing with GOT, or you butcher the story beyond recognition to make it palatable to a larger demographic the way Sam Raimi did when he adapted Sword of Truth to TV.

Comment: im just sorry to say that the saeson 5 has been butchered in a very bad way! And the producers coment he made when asked about why so much deviation... He shouldnt have his job! Lazy, just plain lazy!

Comment: @Cherubel Whatever deviation there was in season 5, it was a streamlining of the books. And it was still so slow-paced many viewers found it frustrating -- imagine if they had translated the books to the TV screen without modification! I applaud the adaptation, but I admit it was slow-paced, mainly because *A Dance with Dragons* is the weakest material in the books.

Comment: FWIW, Batman has multiple cannon/universes. So technically all the Batman origin stories are cannon (unless it's a fanfic)